# exclude item from array list c#

Tags: c#

I am using ASP.NET 2013, I want draw the chart and give different color for each point except some e.g Black, Transparent and so on.

It is working fine but there are some colors I would like to exclude.

```
var colours = typeof(System.Drawing.Color)
               .GetProperties()
               .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
               .Select(x => x.Name)
               .ToArray();

Random rColor = new Random();

foreach (var item in Chart2.Series[0].Points)
{
   item.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(colours[rColor.Next(0, colours.Length)]); 
}
```

Comment: Use a `Color[] excludeColors` and then use `if(!excludeColors.Contains(yourRandomColor){...})`

Comment: Perhaps consider creating your own palette enum of complimentary colours, that way to won't have random ugly clashing colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Color[] excludeColors` and `Except`:

```
Color[] excludeColors = { Color.Black, ... };
var allColors = var colours = typeof(System.Drawing.Color)
               .GetProperties()
               .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(System.Drawing.Color))
               .Select(x => System.Drawing.Color.FromName(x.Name));
Color[] usedColors = allColors.Except(excludeColors).ToArray();

foreach (var item in Chart2.Series[0].Points)
{
   Color randomColor = usedColors[rColor.Next(usedColors.Length)];
   item.Color = randomColor; 
}
```

Since you have to initialize this only once this should be done in the constructor(or where you can modify `excludeColors`) and not in this method.